# Wondering if I can aggregate individual data for binary prediction?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, predictive-models, data-transformation, data-preprocessing

I have an imbalanced dataset. I am looking at aggregating the individual data and thinking about using the aggregated data for binary prediction. The problem is I cannot make my mind whether aggregation on  individual data is fine or not. Is aggregating individual data still a part of data preprocessing?, is this ok to do for binary prediction, and what information do I lose?

Comment: I don't understand.  What does the class balance have to do with aggregation?

Comment: The story goes like this. As far as I know, we can use oversampling, undersampling, and hybrid sampling techniques for an imbalanced dataset. I have been working on an imbalanced dataset for a week and found that even if I do other algorihtms and sampling techniques it just seemed to be, kind of, difficult to reduce the number of false positives.  

Aggregation came into my mind while keeping the number of true positives, I just wanted to reduce the number of true negatives. Doing this, I was kind of afraid that I lose some information that might have important impacts on the dataset.

Comment: How imbalanced are we talking, how many examples of the rare class do you have?  Have you tuned the decision threshold before resorting to the more drastic measures of class reweighting and data set sampling? This is definitely a place where the standard advice is too heavy handed, the first thing to try is adjusting your decision threshold.

Comment: The minority class takes less than 1% of the dataset. The total number of records is 144,460. I could not have any true positives at all with no sampling techniques, so I had to try over-sampling techniques and that gave me some number of true positives.

Comment: Although I had some number for true positives, the precision was about 1.3 which does not seem to make sense to measure the model performance. Although the number of false positives was a tiny fraction of the true negatives, it was still a big number for the number of true positives. I have found "Youden's Index" for a situation like what I have, but I was not so sure about applying "Youden's Index" for the model performance. So I wanted to come up with a way to get a commonly understandable number for precision, that is why I thought about aggregation.

Comment: I didn't try decision threshold adjustments. I was wondering if adjusting the decision threshold adjustment on the training dataset is an overfit to the test dataset. I am not sure about this. You can give me some advice on this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is it ok?

If you only want to do prediction and only measure your performance you can do literaly anything as long as you have an independent test set. Only if you try to use your model for explanation of your independent variables you need to worry about statistical assumptions.

> what information do I lose?

You will lose information that is specific to one of the variables. Anyways, it is always interesting to experiment with your ideas. I would compare all approaches with cross-validation.

Comment: Thank you for answering. Can I apply aggregation to the whole dataset and split them into training and test set? Does the test dataset need to be unchanged?

Comment: It is fine to change your features as long as you do not use information from the test set (except the one example that you are modifying, i.e. the addition), because for normal application you can make the same modifications to them.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you're trying to create more meaningful features (i.e., denser or more informative variables than what you currently have). This is a great question, and there are many many ways to do feature curation and feature engineering, so a lot of it will deal with experimenting with your data.

However, there are techniques (like this paper below) that offer a good starting point to aggregate data and features in a systematic fashion. This paper below specifically uses hiearchical clustering trees when your features are sparse, but there are plenty of other techniques.

*Yan, X., & Bien, J. (2018). Rare feature selection in high dimensions. arXiv preprint arXiv:1803.06675.*

**https://arxiv.org/abs/1803.06675**

Since you mentioned information loss, this paper seems to explain how you can lose information when dichotomizing an discretizing continuous variables. They offer a solution to dos in such a way to minimize information loss.

*Clarke, Ellis J., and Bruce A. Barton. "Entropy and MDL discretization of continuous variables for Bayesian belief networks." International Journal of Intelligent Systems 15, no. 1 (2000): 61-92.*

Hope this helps!